# PyTables table.where equivalent in matlab

Tags: matlab, hdf5, pytables

I'm trying to find something similar in MATLAB to PyTables' [table.where](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref.html#tables.Table.where) that selects a subset of a dataset based on criteria (such as col1 = 4).  So far, my searching has been completely fruitless.  I can't believe such a useful feature wouldn't be supported somehow... can anyone help?

MATLAB ver R2011b.

EDIT: In case it wasn't clear from the question, I'm using an HDF5 file for data storage in MATLAB, hence my desire to find functionality similar to PyTables.

Comment: How do you load that HDF5 format files in matlab?

Comment: @uscere90: what exactly are you looking for, a [dataset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/dataset.html) type in MATLAB, or a way to manipulate [HDF5](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hdf5.html) files?

Comment: @Amro I'm looking for a way to manipulate hdf5 files.  The file I'm working with is too large to load all into ram at once.  I grab a 3d chunk containing the data I want, and then I search through it once matlab has it in memory.  I was hoping I could do it with more elegance, a la pytables' table.where that just returns your matching data right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you try to do involves either `load`-ing the file in memory (or you might give [HDF5 Diskmap Class](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31703) a try if it's to big for memory).

Once you have access to your data in matlab as a matrix, it's easy as:

```
a=[
0 0 0 0 1;
0 1 0 0 1;
1 0 1 1 1;
0 1 1 1 1;
1 0 1 0 1];

a(find(a(:,1)==1),:)
```

Comment: Indeed, this is essentially what I'm doing now.  I was hoping there was an hdf5 function that would only return the matching data, instead of having to load a large gob that's guaranteed to contain the data I want, and then search through it to find it.

Comment: It seems that hdf5read can read out one column of data. That should at least reduce your load. Then you can keep indices matching your criteria, and load those afterwards.